# Node + Typescript + Angular tsconfig and compilation issue

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, lerna

I have this project structure as im using `lerna` to manage my shared/packaged code.

```
 - project
   |- packages
      |- shared
      |- api
      |- web
```

My main deployables would be api and web, this could be extended in the future, and shared could also be broken out in the future.

in shared I have this structure

```
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- src
  |- app.ts
  |- helpers.ts
```

and the first bit of code here is the exporting of my "module"

```
import * as helpers from "./helpers";

export default { helpers };
```

the functions in helpers are pretty straight forward such as.
`export const add = function(x:number,y:number):number{return x+y;}`

When I attempt to use the shared project I get this error from tsc.
`Cannot find module 'shared' or its corresponding type declarations.`
Here is the usage

```
import helpers from 'shared';
import express from 'express';
 
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
 
app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
  console.log(helpers.add(20,10));
  res.send("hello");
});
 
app.listen(port, () => {
  return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

My typescript file in the api and shared projects are exactly the same, I know it's an ever changing world in javascript, and I'm not sure what could be wrong. WIth my limited understanding of typescript, this seems correct.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "lib": ["es2015", "es6"]
  }
```

I have verified in node_modules/shared of the api project that the app.ts is properly updated with every change.

I am including Angular, because I would eventually like to use this shared code in the angular app as well, and I know that it probably will have it's own typescript can of worms as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### Set `main` property

You need to make sure that you are using the `main` property in your `package.json` file. Typescript compiles all of your code into the `dist` directory. With the `main` property in your `package.json` you tell the consuming package where to find the entry file (`dist/app`).

`packages/shared/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "shared",
  "main": "dist/app"
}
```

#### Set `types` property

You want to export type declarations from the `packages/shared` package. Otherwise you won't see the types from `shared` if you import the `shared` package into `api` or `web`. You need to set the `declaration` property in `packages/shared/tsconfig.json` to `true`.

`packages/shared/tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true
  },
    "lib": ["es2015", "es6"]
}
```

Then you need to point the `types` property in `package.json` to `dist/app.d.ts`.

Updated `packages/shared/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "shared",
  "main": "dist/app",
  "types": "dist/app.d.ts"
}
```